# Usage of apply (@) to create sym vector manually in kdb

Tags: kdb

Reference: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb+/#1422-splayed-tables-with-symbol-columns

When doing the enumeration manually,  can someone please explain how is sym vector created using @ in below example?

Example:
I have opened a new q instance:

```
q)t:([] s1:`a`b`c; v:10 20 30; s2:`x`y`z)
q)@[t;exec c from meta t where "s"=t;`sym?] /- Creates a sym vector in memory
q)sym
/- Output - `a`b`c`x`y`z
q)type sym
/- Output - 11h
```

EDIT-
Understood, it is `apply at` which is doing the job, it is equal to updating a list using apply at.
Eg:

```
q)l:2 3 9
q)@[l;1;neg]
2 -3 9
```

Similarly we are applying enum extend to sym vector based on the condition as second argument i.e all sym columns of table t

```
@[t;exec c from meta t where t="s";`sym?]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [@ (amend)](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/) operator is not what generates the `` `sym `` vector, it's the [? (Enum Extend)](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/enum-extend/) operator that does so.

`@` above applies the `` `sym? `` to all columns of `t` which are symbol types. You could instead apply it directly yourself and generate `` `sym ``:

```
q)show t:([] s1:`a`b`c; v:10 20 30; s2:`x`y`z)
s1 v  s2
--------
a  10 x
b  20 y
c  30 z
q)sym
'sym
  [0]  sym
       ^
q)`sym?t`s1
`sym$`a`b`c
q)sym
`a`b`c
q)`sym?t`s2
`sym$`x`y`z
q)sym
`a`b`c`x`y`z
```

`` `sym `` is created when we first call the function, and continues to be extended whenever we call it again.